# SqlBulkCopy dealing with nulls

Tags: c#, .net, sqlbulkcopy

I am using SqlBulkCopy to upload lots of data to an SQL table. It works very well apart from one thing (always the way).

So in my c# app, I have a function. It receives a variable myObj of type object (from Matlab). The object is actually an array.

I create a DataTable where I specify the column type & read in the data from myObj. One of the columns (let's call it salary) in the table is of type double.

**The problem**

If one of the rows has a NaN value for salary the upload won't work, it returns the message below.

> OLE DB provider 'STREAM' for linked server '(null)' returned invalid data for column

What I need in the database is the row to be uploaded but with the Salary, column to have a value of null. Is there any way of doing this?

The only crude way I have come up with is testing for when the value is null ( or NaN) in my c# app and assigning it a value of -999 and then after the upload updating any values from -999 to null. However, this seems like a poor workaround.

Comment: Just make your column nullable

Comment: This should be possible; could we see a [mcve] please?